# Pdf files are not tracked by service in Windows 10 but in windows 7 they are tracked by service

Tags: windows-10, windows-services, microsoft-edge

We have a windows service in vb dot net that can easily track the pdf files in windows 7 but in windows 10 pdf files are not being tracked by the service. In windows 10 pdf files are open on Microsoft Edge but our service cannot track these files. On internet explorer these files get tracked but on edge those files are not .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how do you track the browser's behavior using the windows service? please explain more details about that.

Besides, I think perhaps the issue is related that they are using different PDF viewer.

In the IE browser, it will use the Adobe PDF Reader add-on to open the PDF file, but in the Microsoft Edge browser, since it will not have any support for ActiveX plug-ins. Therefore, the Acrobat/Reader plug-in won't work with Edge. For more information, see [Change in support for Acrobat and Reader plug-ins in modern web browsers](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/change-in-support-for-acrobat-and-reader-plug-ins-in-modern-web-.html).

So, it can be possible that it is Edge default behavior. You might need to change your code to track the pdf file.